# how to customize header row of Table component (in codenameone )

Tags: codenameone

How can I achieve header structure as shown in the image so I can have some level of discrimination  on parameters provided in the Table component. [image]

If you see in the diagram Table is divided into two parts Hot side and Cold side.There are some parameters under hot side and some parameters under cold side. At least this much is required.

I'm modifying my question based on the your ans :

```
String[][] tableData = {
                 { "Density", "Volume Flow", "T (in)","T (out)","Flow", "Specific Heat", "Density", "Volume Flow", 
                    "T (in)","T (out)","Flow", "Specific Heat", "Duty", "UA"}
         };

    final CustomTableModel tableModel = new CustomTableModel (
                new String[]  {"Hot Side", "","","","","Cold Side","","","","","",""}, tableData,true);

dataTable =  new Table(tableModel) {


         @Override
            protected Constraint createCellConstraint(Object value, int row, int column) {

                Constraint con = super.createCellConstraint(value, row, column);
                if(row == -1 && (column == 0 || column == 5) ) {
                    con.setHorizontalSpan(5);
                }
                return con;
            }
        @Override
        protected Component createCell(Object value, final int row, final int column, boolean editable) {

            if(row == -1) {
                    final Button headerButton = new Button((String)value);
                    headerButton.setUIID(getUIID() + "Header");
                    headerButton.getUnselectedStyle().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
                    headerButton.getSelectedStyle().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
                    headerButton.setFlatten(true);


                   return headerButton;
               }
                // Conditions for Other rows
                   ...
            }
```

I have only two columns "Hot Side" and "Cold Side" in header row and 14 columns in rest of the rows. I tried different condition but didn't get this structure. What conditions should I put in to get the structure. I think I am doing something wrong here.

This is what I tried :

```
            @Override
            protected Constraint createCellConstraint(Object value, int row, int column) {

                Constraint con = super.createCellConstraint(value, row, column);
                if(row == -1 && (column == 0 || column == 5) ) {
                    con.setHorizontalSpan(5);
                }
                return con;
            }
```

My TableModel is :

```
final CustomTableModel tableModel = new CustomTableModel (
                new String[]  {"Hot Side", "","","","","Cold Side","","","","","",""}, tableData,true);
```

This is the preview of screen :
[image]

Comment: You should provide whole information in your question. I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize any cell in the table by overriding the `createCell` method, this includes the header cells which are marked as -1 row if I remember correctly.

In this case the header area needs to "span" which you can do by overriding the constraint behavior:

```
protected TableLayout.Constraint createCellConstraint(Object value, int row, int column) {
    TableLayout.Constraint tl = super.createCellConstraint(value, row, column);
    if(this is the cell I want to span) {
       tl.setHorizontalSpan(4);
    }
    return tl;
}
```

Comment: I have modified the question based on your answer. It is spanning but not in a right way. What I did is applied it for -1 row  and column 0 and 1. But I get blank  Table. I tried some other conditions too by putting empty columns in header row, in this case I get half part of the Table (Hot side only) . Is it necessary to have same no of columns in header row and rest of the rows ?

Comment: Hard to tell, I suggest you try a simple test case with smaller sample then narrow down what exactly breaks for you.

Comment: If I'm using two columns for header row then it takes two columns for rest of rows as well( which I don't want clearly). Even if I add empty columns in the header row and try to expand only two,few columns overlap each other in header row and showing few columns( 7 or 8 out of 14) in remaining rows. What do you suggest for this condition ?

Comment: If I understand correctly you need to do the span only on the specific column you want to span and ignore the rest e.g. if(row == -1 && column == 0)

Comment: I have tried it before (one of many conditions). This time I have attached the screenshot as well. Here in the screenshot you can see many columns in header row. I don't want empty columns here, just two columns -- "Hot Side" and "Cold Side". Is it possible to achieve just like my first screenshot I shared (Look for the header row)  ?

Comment: I got another issue because of `createCellConstraint(Object value, int row, int column)` method. Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29234292/exception-occured-while-dynamically-changing-cell-values-if-overriding-createcel) after responding to my previous comment.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? I have one but it doesn't have to do with Table Component. I can place a Container with Labels - "Hot Side" and "Cold Side" before Table Component to represent header row. I'm saving it as my last option.

Comment: That looks like a bug. I'd suggest you file an issue in the issue tracker but you'd better hurry since we are closing it temporarily in preparation for the github migration http://codenameone.com/blog/github-migration-plan.html